# Why `ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED` does take so much time to update status?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Bluetooth Low Energy to connect with my galaxy S4. After connection, the connection status will be updated in the function

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        String intentAction;
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Connected");                

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Disconnected");                
        }
    }
}
```

In which, the status got from

```
// Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
```

However, the `ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED` takes 10 seconds to update when the connection between the BLE device and the phone lost. In the case of `ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED`, it updates so fast about 1 seconds. Is it possible to reduce the disconnection status in BLE? Thank all

Comment: What do you mean with "reduce the disconnection status"? What takes 10 seconds to update? What exactly does broadcastUpdate do?

Comment: Thank Nebr for considering my question. I will give you an example what I did. My BLE has two buttons: turn on and turn off. When it turn on, the BLE will connect with my phone. It takes about 1 seconds to display the log `Connected`. When these devices connected, I turn off my BLE device, but it takes about 10 seconds to display `Disconnected`. I want to reduce that time.

Comment: That is in fact strange. Disconnecting is just a terminate request on link layer that does not even need to be responded - one side can disconnect without consent of the other. Can you isolate the problematic region? What is the condition for displaying "Disconnected"? Are you waiting for a termination acknowledged event from a lower layer? Can you check what the link layer does when you disconnect the devices? Do you maybe have a timeout of 10 seconds somewhere that is running out?

Comment: Do you have experiment with BLE connection. I am using sample code of BLE chat

Comment: I don't have that sample code, sorry. Nor will it probably help much. It will be necessary to debug the existing system. I would put my money on the assumption that a timeout occurs when trying to disconnect, because the system waits for an event that never comes, but without more details (what does broadcastUpdate do, when is the UI display updated etc.) it will be impossible to find out.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a 'link supervision timeout', this is defined as the amount of time the link must be maintained before giving up. This is why it takes so long when your peripheral device stops communicating.

```
// Link supervision timeout is measured in N * 10ms
int timeout = 2000; // 20s
```

You can find relevant code starting at line 1646 in com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/2b42a4906be952d3761d8b47134fba5a277a7765/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java

**---- Edit ----**

The bigger problem seems to be a known bug with lollipop and kitcat in which bluedroid caches devices during discovery when it's not supposed to, see issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81130&q=BLE&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

There is no way to edit the timeout unless you can compile your own aosp system rom and flash to device.

There is a possible *hack* to work around this problem but it is not recommend because it is accessing a hidden internal API which may not exist starting in marshmallow (as bluedroid dropped for bluez).

**The hack:**

After calling disconnect and close force the discovery cache to refresh via reflectively calling the refresh method.

```
BluetoothGatt localBluetoothGatt = gatt;
Method localMethod = localBluetoothGatt.getClass().getMethod("refresh", new Class[0]);
if (localMethod != null) {
    localMethod.invoke(localBluetoothGatt, new Object[0])).booleanValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we change the time?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, I was tried it but it has same issue. The reconnection time is still long

Comment: @user8430 Maybe try a different a component, I like the hm-10 personally.

Comment: Do you think hm-10 can connect faster than my device csr 1010? Do you use it before?

Comment: I have used it before and I know it's a high quality chip, however my integration was into an android device requiring a custom serial driver so I had full control of the stack without the limitations you are facing. So I am not sure if it will remedy the situation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Which BLE device are you using to test the connection?. It could be possible that the device is actually closing the connection after some time. In some cases BLE device will close the connection after some time because it might have to write some characteristics which you have requested. In some cases it actually depends on the device Embedded code to determine when to close the connection.

In my situation my BLE device will close the connection after 5 secs. That 5 secs is like a buffer for the device to send me any pending write, read characteristics that i have requested.

We have configured our BLE device to notify when the end of broadcast broadcast which i used to notify user that the connection has been closed but in the background the BLE device is still open for 5 secs so that it can write some characteristics or user may want to regain the connection.

Comment: My device is csr 1010 as follows http://www.broadband.se/shop/bluetooth/bluetooth-smart/devboard/csr-1010-tag-dev-board/

Comment: I tried to disconnect by calling the function disconnect(), it will disconnect directly. But when I reconnect again.  it also has same issue delay time

Comment: Ok... So, the device doesn't disconnect automatically and you are disconnecting through the app and after disconnecting when you try to connect again you are seeing the delay. Is that correct ?

Comment: In the BLE device, it has a switch to disconnect by turn off the power. However, the connection state  still maintains connected when I turn off the power. After 10 seconds, the app. will  update the connection state as disconnected. To solve that issue, my device sends a command to disconnect it manually. When I receive the command, I will disconnect by function `disconnect()`. After that, I reconnect it by call the connect function but the time still long. I think the interval time about 10~20 seconds

Comment: Can you try calling gatt.close() also after disconnect()

Comment: Yes. I called it after I call disconnect()

Comment: Hmm.. Ok download this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.billy.billylightblue&hl=en and select your app in the list of devices and then see if there is any delay

Comment: Thanks. I am not in office now. I will test and feedback to you tomorrow

Comment: Ok.. check this app too.. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner&hl=en

Comment: I checked your second suggestion before  and it has same issue.

Comment: I tried both your suggestion apps. But they are has same issue.